# Batch create folder based on partial file name and move files to folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, reorganize

I have a series of .wav files with similar file names. Each file has a first and last name followed by the date and a number. I would like to create a series of files based on the first and last name and then move the files to the matching file path.

Example:

```
John_Doe_1-6-6-2021 15-23_123453245.wav
John_Doe_1-6-6-2021 15-23_12345874.wav
John_Doe_1-6-6-2021 15-23_1239964.wav

Mary_Walker_1-6-6-2021 15-23_123453245.wav
Mary_Walker_1-6-6-2021 15-23_1778941.wav
Mary_Walker_1-6-6-2021 15-23_8741556899.wav
```

I would like those files to be organized similar to the following:

```
SourceDirectory
 |> John_Doe_1
     |> John_Doe_1-6-6-2021 15-23_123453245.wav
     |> John_Doe_1-6-6-2021 15-23_12345874.wav
     |> John_Doe_1-6-6-2021 15-23_1239964.wav

 |> Mary_Walker_1
   |> Mary_Walker_1-6-6-2021 15-23_123453245.wav
   |> Mary_Walker_1-6-6-2021 15-23_1778941.wav
   |> Mary_Walker_1-6-6-2021 15-23_8741556899.wav
```

At the moment I have this script. The script will create a folder based on the First Name and moves the files there (Which is great), the only issue is I need the first name, last name and the 1 at the end. So the Folder should be like `John Doe 1` not just `John` or `John Doe`.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\JohnUser\Desktop\Test\"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "* *_*-* *.*"'
 ) DO (  
 MD %%a
MOVE "%%a %%b" .\%%a\
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF

pause
```

Comment: Your `dir` command line would not match any of your example files. Anyway, there is a `delims` option of `for /F` that should be useful…

Comment: I wish I knew what that meant. Forgive me as I am a beginner and would not know where to begin with what you've mentioned.

Comment: Type `help for` and read the screen. You need "delims=_- " (note the trailing space).

Comment: On second thought, you probably want "tokens=3,* delims=_- ".

Comment: I recommend avoiding the `pushd`/`popd` in your script. If the script breaks in the middle for some reason, the `popd` will never happen and your script will have failed poorly. Use `dir /b /a-d "%sourceDir%\* *_*-* *.*"` instead. Adjust the `md` and `move` commands accordingly.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult but I am a beginner and trying to understand. As of right now, I updated the code to include `"tokens=3,* delims=_- "` but still get the same issue where it will not create a folder. Or it says that the folder/file already exists and closes out.

Comment: Before typing `for /?` into a Command Prompt window and learning how to use `for /F` and it's `delims` option, step back and check by what criterion the file names are to be split…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using the `-` character as the delimiter, `Delims`, to perform the fiilename string split. *(You could use `Tokens=1`, but as that is the default, I have left it out)*:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "SourceDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\Test"
For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "%SourceDir%":"?*-?*-?*-???? ??-??_?*.wav"'
) Do For /F "Delims=-" %%H In ("%%~nG") Do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%SourceDir%" "%SourceDir%\%%H" "%%~nxG" /Mov 1>NUL
)
```

*To understand how any command works, open a Command Prompt window, type `Command /?`. For example `for /?`, `where /?`, `robocopy /?`.*

Comment: Apologies on my delayed response. I checked from my phone and was not able to test until today. I have tested and it does work with the requirements that were asked for. Thank you!